# How can I get the top path of glob path?

Tags: go, path, glob

e.g.

```
a/b/c* -> a/b
a/b/c*/*/*b -> a/b
```

Why I need this is because I want to get the abs path of globed filename.
Code example:

```
files, _ := filepath.Glob(p)
top := __magic here__
for _, f := range files {
    abs, _ := filepath.Abs(path.Join(top, f))
    fmt.Println(abs)
}
```

Is there any exists method for this purpose? otherwise I have to implement by myself.

**EDIT**

The magic is make glob path abs first, then the glob return abs path.

Comment: File names returned by `filepath.Glob()` are already absolute, aren't they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File names returned by [`filepath.Glob()`](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Glob) are already absolute (but read below).

See this example:

```
fs, err := filepath.Glob("/dev/../dev/*")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
for _, f := range fs {
    fmt.Println(f, filepath.IsAbs(f))
}
```

Output:

```
/dev/null true
/dev/random true
/dev/urandom true
/dev/zero true
```

Try it on the <kbd>[Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/ABFGMhhgV0)</kbd>.

**Edit:**

The returned file names are only absolute if the glob pattern is absolute. So the easiest way is to make the glob pattern absolute.

Comment: If you use the relative path to glob, the path is relative, try [this](http://play.golang.org/p/XiOivBFEhE), but thank you, I can make glob path abs then do glob, the path will be abs.